# Error subtracting times

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to subtract a PM time and AM in Excel 2013. I am getting the `#####` error.

Example:

```
A1=7:00 PM B2=12:30 AM

=+A1-B2
```

I have the cell formatted in time, but it comes back with the error.

Please help.

Comment: I can only reproduce this when the subtraction is done the other way, i.e., when the result is negative.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your times are actually stored as dates by Excel, counting up from 12:00 AM, January 1, 1900. Any time before that date is not recognized as a valid date-time. So, when you subtract a later time from an earlier time, the result is not recognized as a valid date-time.

There is a workaround though.

Go to `Excel Options` > `Advanced` > `When Calculating This Workbook`. Check the box labeled `Use the 1904 date system`. This will allow you to show negative times on your worksheet. ([Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/182247))

If your goal is to calculate that time difference as from one day to the next (i.e., `12:30 AM - 7:30 PM = 5:30`, not `-18:30`), after changing this setting in Excel, you can adjust your formula to do this.

Instead of

```
=B2-A1
```

You can use

```
=IF(B2-A1<0,1+B2-A1,B2-A1)
```

This will always return a positive time difference when subtracting simple times.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the result is negative.

If the start time is greater than the end time, add 12 to the end time before subtracting:

`=IF(A1>B2,(B2+12)-A1,B2-A1)`

Note that your method of tracking (without a day) will break if the start and end times are the same. Is this special case 0 or 24 hours?

If you are on 24 hour time, add 24 instead. Better yet, figure out a way to append the date, which ought to allow the internal functions to track e.g. daylight savings time, leap years, apocalypse etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for one of my Time sheet examples

How it looks

[image: The Setup]

the formula

[image: Formula]

```
=((E7<D7)+E7-D7+(G7<F7)+G7-F7)
```

You can also use rounddown, to round the time to 15 minutes. So if the employee stayed till 12:46 AM, the Total Hours would be 5:25

```
=ROUNDDOWN(((E7<D7)+E7-D7+(G7<F7)+G7-F7)/TIME(0,15,0),0)*TIME(0,15,0)
```